# Accessing a symbol table through typescript's compiler-api

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm trying to construct a graph of variable defines and usages in a typescript program.

I was using typescript's `compiler-api` to achieve this. By playing around a little, i see that each node is associated with a `Symbol` object, which associates a `symbolFlag` with it. What's the right way to access this `symbolFlag` from a `Node` object?

This is what I've tried so far -

```
function get_variable_names(node: ts.Node, pgm: ts.Program): void{
        var nodes: ts.Node[] = [];
        function getNodes(sf: ts.Node): ts.Node[] {
            var nodes: ts.Node[] = [];
            function allNodes(n: ts.Node) {
                ts.forEachChild(n, n => { nodes.push(n); allNodes(n); return false; })
            };
            allNodes(sf);
            return nodes;
        }
        var id_nodes = getNodes(node).filter(n => n.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.Identifier);
        const checker = pgm.getTypeChecker()
        const names = id_nodes.map(n => (checker.getSymbolAtLocation(n).getDeclarations()));
        // Not really sure here.
        console.log(names);
    }
```

Moreover, i get a compile error saying `Cannot read property 'getDeclarations' of undefined`.

Further, I realize i can manually construct a graph, if, for each identifier, i look at its symbol information and gather where it was declared, this inferring whether it's a variable.

But is there a quicker way to achieve this? I suspect there's an in-built way of doing this? Couldn't spot it in the documentations.

Comment: How did you solve it? Have you found a canonical way of doing that? Wanna do the exact same. Is there a solution out there for that use case? (Graph)